# iCarousel View in a table cell view does not scroll at all

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell, icarousel

I put the iCarousel View in a table View and try to scroll the iCarousel, but the problem is it's not scrollable at all.

I can see iCarousel in the cell like following:

[image]

and I put iCarousel datasource and delegate in the tableView Controller, create a customer function to set the iCarousel datasource and delegate.

In the CustomTableViewCell I just define the setting delegate function:

```
- (void) setICarouselDataSourceDelegate:    (id<iCarouselDelegate,iCarouselDataSource>)dataSourceDelegate {
self.carousel.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
self.carousel.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
[self.carousel reloadData];
```

}

and in the MainTableView, I call the DataSourceDelegate in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all iCarousel is not any standarad View ... you should put link of the control that you're using

Second it seems like iCarousel is uses UIScrollView and UITableView is also derived from UIScrollView  It's never a good idea to put a scrollview inside another scrollview.

This might be the reason why your table view is not scrolling.... BTW are you talking about horizontal scrollign or vertical scrolling ?

Comment: Not an answer. Use comments for requesting clarifications. Nested scroll views are explicitly supported per Apple's doc.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using the iCarousel in Table View cell and it scrolls easily.

1. Just add standard view to cell in Storyboard.
2. In IB mark the class of that view to iCarousel.
3. Furthermore !**ENABLE**! user interaction on that view. (Maybe because of that you can't scroll the content inside the cell)
4. Implement separate datasource & delegate for every cell. (It is more clear which data are loading in the cell and also the cell itself can handle the data. You just pass the data to cell and it handles it accordingly.) - But it depends on you if you want to let one class to handle two separate control datasources & delegates :-)

Comment: Is it possible to send me your source code? I still can not fix the problem even if I followed the steps.

Comment: Another problem is, I am not using storyboard, so how can I define the IB mark.

Comment: view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
And what do you use ? If you are adding the iCarousel manually ? I do not get the problem.